# Embed youtube video with subtitle into iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, youtube

I'm trying to embed YouTube video into iphone app and using UIWebView and loading embed code from youtube as html string. but i want to control the subtitle show/change or not.

this is my code

```
you2WebView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,70, 300, 300)];
you2WebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
you2WebView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
[self.view addSubview:you2WebView];

NSString* embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                       <html>\
                       <body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'>\
                       <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'>\
                       </script>\
                       <script type='text/javascript'>\
                       function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()\
                       {\
                       ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{\
                       events:{\
                       'onReady':onPlayerReady,\
                       }\
                       })\
                       }\
                       function onPlayerReady(a)\
                       {\
                       a.target.playVideo();\
                       }\
                       </script>\
                            <iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='%d' height='%d' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?rel=1&playsinline=1' frameborder='0'>\
                       </body>\
                       </html>", 300, 200, @"MOqfyGNNKvo"];
[you2WebView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

and this is my button action code

```
-(void)clickedProgramBtn01{
[you2WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"ytplayer.getOptions('cc')"];
NSLog(@"clicked!");
}
```

but it doesn't show the subtitle on video :'(

i want to show the subtitle on youtube video when i clicked ProgramBtn01

what should i do?

Comment: define "doesn't work". Can't play?

Comment: What are you doing with `embedHTML`? You don't refer back to it at all...

Comment: sorry,forgot to post embedHTML

Comment: what you want to exact first caption of your youtubevideo?

Comment: can play ,but the app can't show caption on video

Comment: you can get caption of your youtube video using url also try this :- http://img.youtube.com/vi/MOqfyGNNKvo/1.jpg

Comment: sorry...my English is pool:(
i mean the subtitle with video

Comment: check my url its give the caption of your video its working for me

Comment: thanks,but i want control the subtitle show/change language like
http://ppt.cc/GyBQ